# Shopping cart to sell a B2B software with upgrade possibility

Tags: ecommerce, shopping-cart

I have to build a website that sells 3 versions of a software: a basic version, a medium one and an advanced one. It's the same software but with more features.

Selling them as 3 stand alone products, it's no problem. Any shopping cart can do this.

In my case, I'm looking for a shopping cart that allows only one version to be bought and with the possibility for a customer to login and upgrade.

If somebody buys the basic version, he should be able to come back later, login and update to the medium one, not to buy the medium one.

If anyone can suggest a good tool for this, that would be great.

I can develop the static part of the website using any tool but the ecommerce part is causing me troubles.

Comment: A workaround would be to sell the upgrade as a separate product. Your webshop would then have 5 products (or 6 if you allow an upgrade from basic to advanced). This is a common way many sites handles this.

Comment: Thank you, Jan, for your answer. It's not a bad idea but I think it may be confusing for the customers. There must be a shopping cart that allows a customer to login, see what he has already bought and also upgrade. I'll keep searching. :)

Comment: Is it imaginable that a company has bought you 7 basic versions and 13 advanced versions? Or is it just one "version level" for each customer, and no customer would buy several times the same thing?

Comment: A company can only buy one software and they the possibility to upgrade. They cannot buy 2 software products. So, once you buy, you can see what you have bought and upgrade (if you did not buy the best version). That's all.